# Use of 予定 at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar, syntax

I'm currently reading this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011636501000/k10011636501000.html)

Which has the following sentence:

> インドで人気がある小さい炊飯器を輸出する予定です。
>
> My translation: There is a plan to export small rice cookers, which have become popular in India.

The sentence ends with **予定です** but I don't understand why. I would expect it to end with 予定があります instead. Since for me 予定があります would translate to "there is a plan", where just 予定です would be "it's a plan"

Comment: The copula だ (and all its variations like です, である, etc) usually can be translated as the verb "to be". Example: 私は学生です( I am a student).
But the copula だ can also be used to simplify the sentence and replace other verbs.
Example: 私はコーヒーを飲む。家内は紅茶だ。(I drink coffee. My wife drinks tea).
家内は紅茶だ does not mean "My wife is tea". だ here is replacing the verb "drink".
As long as it can be understood from the context, you can use だ to replace other verbs
You could say 予定があります or 予定をしました.  But most Japanese people will simplify the sentence and say 予定だ。
https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/予定である

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**～予定です** is like "is planned"

eg:

> 外食する予定です。
>
> I plan to eat out.
>
> lit: "eating out is planned"

**～予定があります** is like  "there are plans"

eg:

> その日は予定があります。
>
> I have plans on that day.
>
> lit: "on the topic of that day, there are plans"

So, applying this logic to your example sentence:

> It is planned to export small rice cookers popular in India.

Comment: As soon as I read that first line everything hit me like a ton of bricks. Makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: "今日の午後医者へ行く予定にしている" is translated in Reverso by 'I'm going to go to the doctor this afternoon.' I conclude that 予定する is near-grammaticalized, because it sometimes can be used as a near future conjugation marker, like in the former example.